# Cloud Foundry App is showing 5GB of memory usage but heap dump shows just few MBs

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, memory-management, cloud-foundry

I have a Spring based JAVA Web App deployed in Cloud Foundry (running on Tomcat8 and compiled on JAVA8).

After couple of calls (payload size is 15MB per request) to application the memory rises to 5GB.

I took the heap dump using cf plugin `cf java heap-dump`, surprisingly the leak analysis on heap dump showed just few MBs per thread (there was one thread per request).

I did `ssh` login to the app and ran `top` command which again showed java process consuming 5GB!

To restrict the memory of app, I added following `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable (just to check if that restricts the app memory):

`-Xmx=512M -XX:MarkStackSizeMax=512M -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=512M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -XX:CICompilerCount=5 -Xss=512M -Xmx=512M -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=30M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512M`

Even after this, there was no change and couple of calls lead to same 5GB usage of memory.

Further, I ran `pmap` command and I got following response:

[image]

I am not understanding what is first 2 rows with maximum memory usage.

What can be the possible cause for such high memory usage, if the heap dump doesn't show it?

Comment: What is being reported when you run `cf app <your-app>`?

Comment: @DanielMikusa: it shows 5GB...

Comment: It could be a number of things, but if `cf app` reports 5G in use then something in the container is using that. I would remove all of your custom JVM memory settings, let the buildpack handle that. Then set a lower memory limit. If you only want it to use 1G or 2G, then set that as the memory limit. The Java buildpack will size your app so it doesn't use more memory than that.

Comment: Also, it's important to understand the JVM's heap isn't ever going to take up the full memory limit of the container. There are other processes in the container that take up a small amount of memory, there are also other memory regions in the Java process that will take up sometimes non-insignificant amounts of memory. You can use Java NMT to explore those non-heap regions, some APM tools might show this information as well.

Comment: @DanielMikusa: Thanks for the suggestions. 1) I will try to reduce the memory and check how it behaves
2) For using NMT - should I start the app with -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail and then ssh and use jcmd? Do you have any documentation?
3) I found one more interesting thing (may not be exactly relevant to this issue) - My VM memory limit id 8G but the 'top` command shows KiB Mem : 26110456+total which translated to ~26G...

Comment: `top` is not accurate because you're in a container. It looks at the entire VM, not just your container. That's why I suggested looking at `cf app` because it knows about your container limits specifically. I haven't had to enable Java NMT in a while, but this is what I used to do: https://github.com/dmikusa/cf-debug-tools#use-profile-to-dump-the-jvm-native-memory